# IBM Cloud CLI: Attempt to install COS CLI plug-in fails on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ibm-cloud

I am unable to install IBM Cloud Object Storage CLI plug-in on Ubuntu 20.04.

When I attempt to install, I receive the following error:

```
ibmcloud plugin install cloud-object-storage
Looking up 'cloud-object-storage' from repository 'IBM Cloud'...

FAILED
Could not find compatible binary to install for plug-in cloud-object-storage.
```

Comment: Include the steps you performed

Comment: Sure, at the command prompt, I entered the following command:  ibmcloud plugin install cloud-object-storage

Comment: and obtained the following error:

Comment: Looking up 'cloud-object-storage' from repository 'IBM Cloud'...
FAILED
Could not find compatible binary to install for plug-in cloud-object-storage.

Comment: Try an update to your CLI environment first: `ibmcloud update`. Compatible could also mean related to your CLI version.